# Magento2 graphQl special_price filter not working

Tags: products, graphql, magento2.4.5, magento-graphql

I am trying to retrieve all products holding a special price value.

```
{
  products(filter: {
      
        special_price: { from: "0.00" ,to:"10.00"}
    }, 
    sort: {
        name: ASC
    }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sale
      special_price
      special_from_date
      special_to_date
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          final_price {
            value
            currency
          }
          discount {
            amount_off
            percent_off
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Above is the example query which is trying to run. But it always returns a null result. Does anyone know why it's returning null?

Comment: This will not work because "special_price" is not in the filter attribute list. Please refer to this link https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/products/queries/products/#filter-attribute

Comment: Refer to this link for customization related to filter using "special_price" https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/usage/custom-filters/